# Python - Create List from Recursive Loop

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop, recursion

I'm trying to create a list from my recursive loop. I know it is able to produce the results I need since I've already checked that by printing the results.

Here's my recursive loop:

```
def move_forward_occurences(occurrences, firstListDt):
    listingResults = []
    for x in range(0, occurrences):
        firstListDt = firstListDt + relativedelta(bdays=+2)
        listingResults.extend(firstListDt)
        return listingResults
```

Alternatively, the problem could be that I'm not checking it correctly:

```
if occurrences != 0:
    listingResult = move_forward_occurences(occurrences, firstListDt)
    for result in listingResult:
        print(result)
```

An explanation of parameters if needed (they're pretty self explanatory already):
occurrences = number of times to produce result
firstListDt = start date

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Loops... aren't recursive...

Comment: " I know it is able to produce the results I need since I've already checked that by printing the results." Then, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` is overly indented. You want to defer the return until after the `for` loop has finished:

```
def move_forward_occurences(occurrences, firstListDt):
    listingResults = []
    for x in range(0, occurrences):
        firstListDt = firstListDt + relativedelta(bdays=+2)
        listingResults.extend(firstListDt)
    return listingResults
```